# How to create .txt and .csv files in Unix?

Tags: unix, terminal

I'm learning how to use the terminal and manage unix and I was wondering what is the way to make a .txt and a .csv to store some text information.

Answer (score 1):

1. Navigate to the desired directory, e.g. `cd Documents/SomeFolder`
2. Run `touch fileName.txt` to create the file.
3. Run `nano fileName.txt` or `vim fileName.txt` to edit the file with *nano* or *vim* respectively.*

P.S. you can also skip the second step as once you exit and save the file it will automatically save it to the directory if it does not exist yet, so creating the file prior is not necessary.

---

*I prefer using nano as it is simple to use, once you are done editing simply press `ctrl + x` and it will prompt if you want to save before exiting. Vim is slightly more complex and you need to press `i` to enter insertion (editing) mode, then once you are done you need to press `esc` to exit insertion mode and then type `:wq` and enter to save.

Comment: Thank you! I'm actually learning to use Vim more than nano, so any tips are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "this is some text" > file.txt
echo "name,age,address" > file.csv
echo "Bob,37,123 Main St." >> file.csv
cat << EOF >> file.csv
Alice,34,23 Elm St.
Charlie,23,60 E. Birch Ave.
EOF
```